# Removing upside down flange nut in a deep hole

Tags: stuck-bolt, exhaust-manifold

My friend worked on my car to replace the exhaust manifold/cat converter gasket and I noticed rattling noise as if something was loose. Checking with my a bore-scope camera with my phone, I saw the flange nut being put the wrongway in the manifold stud and to make matters worse, it is in a deep hole so I can't get any tools in.
[image]

The manifold nuts that is stuck looks like this

[image]

the location where the bolt is stuck is circled in red

[image]

Would anyone have any tricks or idea as to how to remove this.
Thanks

Comment: Is this on a stud or a bolt? If a bolt, can you get to the other end (bolt head)?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, It is a stude. The flange nut is threaded wrong way on a stud.

Comment: I wonder how he managed to put that nut on?  Even locating it on the stud would have been difficult, not being able to put it in a socket.

Comment: how deep is the hole, exactly? Too deep for needle nose pliers?

Comment: @SortofDamocles , Yes, pliers are too short, even if the pliers were long, don't think there is enough room for it to open wide to grab the top and bottom part of the flange nut.

Comment: Everyone has missed the obvious answer: Give it back to the "friend" to fix - make him suffer through the fix for his, um, "workmanship".

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion:

Find another flange nut which is the same type, a  flange nut with the "grippers" (don't know what else to call them) on it. Drill out the threads just enough so it won't catch on the threads of the stud. Then put a little bit of electrical tape on the hex portion of it so it will stick in your socket. Next, use some carb cleaner or something and clean the flange side of the stuck nut. Then put your modified nut down on top of it (flange side first, of course). While putting downward pressure on the whole get up, slowly try to loosen the nut which is upside down. The grippers from both flange nuts should counter each other and grab, making it so you can take the upside down one out.

Answer (score 2):

I had an idea of using a 12pt socket that is a tiny bit smaller than the flange, put on extension, hammer on, then unbolt. I did not have a flange nut to test, so tried with a nut and washer which is not exactly the same, I know. The washer bent over and gripped the socket. I had to hammer it out
[image]

Comment: Definitely worth a try.  May work if the socket is just the right size.

Answer (score 0):

There do exist specialty pliers for this sort of situation, if you are able and willing to buy a new tool for the job. See for example: [link to ACE hardware](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/tools/hand-tools/solid-joint-pliers/2368983?store=03102&gclid=Cj0KCQjwmouZBhDSARIsALYcouoOVJl29644UIoInD8UI_Ju_qJ11lcdh4P-EJ9gwnq1ixM_e8gJ4pUaAl82EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Answer (score 0):

I'd get some soft metal (aluminum?) tubing that has an "interference fit" on the flange, hammer it down (so it grips the nut) and use pliers to unscrew it.

Fabricating such "helpers" is one of the reasons why shops often have a lathe around.

Even some fitting plastic tubing could work if the nut isn't seized (then perhaps even a fitting rubber hose).